# Возможно ли создать Proxy-класс только из интерфейса

Tags: java, proxy

Всем добрый день.
К примеру есть у меня лишь интерфейс, без реализации каким-либо классом.
Имеется ли какая-то возможно создать прокси класс на основе этого интерфейса, без необходимости создания экземпляра класса, реализующего этот интерфейс?

Comment: А что тогда ваш прокси будет проксировать?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> без необходимости создания экземпляра класса, реализующего этот интерфейс?

Прокси класс и будет классом, реализующим интерфейс. Отличие от реализации обычного класса в том, что его создание происходит в runtime.

[Proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html):

> A dynamic proxy class (simply referred to as a proxy class below) is a class that implements a list of interfaces specified at runtime when the class is created, with behavior as described below. A proxy interface is such an interface that is implemented by a proxy class. A proxy instance is an instance of a proxy class.

Реализация всех методов интерфейсов прокси определяется в экземпляре класса `InvocationHandler`.

Например у меня есть интерфейс с 2 методами:

```
private interface Foo {
    void method1();
    void method2();
    void method3();
}
```

Я хочу создать прокси, который бы реализовывал `method1`, а на все остальные ничего не делал (либо бросал исключение, что метод не реализован). Это можно сделать, например, так:

```
public static void main(String... arg) {
    Foo foo = (Foo) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Foo.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{Foo.class}, (proxy, method, args) -> {
        switch (method.getName()) {
            case "method1":
                System.out.println("method1");
                return null;
            default:
                break;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(method.getName() + " is not implemented");
    });
    foo.method1();
    foo.method2();
}
```

Результат выполнения:

> method1
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: method2 is not implemented
>       ...

Comment: оно ! спасибо.  Не пойму как пометить этот комментарий правильным ответом. нет такой кнопки

Comment: @srg321 серая галочка рядом с ответом (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png)